# Why doesn't zurb foundation off-canvas work in my project?

Tags: canvas, zurb-foundation

I am using the latest version of Foundation to add an off-canvas navigation menu.
This is my test page code for work with foundation off-canvas:

```
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Foundation | Welcome</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="off-canvas-wrap show-for-small-only">
            <div class="inner-wrap">
                <nav class="tab-bar show-for-small-only">
                    <section class="tab-bar-section">
                        <h1 class="title">Foundation</h1>
                    </section>
                    <section class="right-small">
                        <a class="right-off-canvas-toggle menu-icon"><span></span></a>
                    </section>
                </nav>
                <aside class="right-off-canvas-menu">
                    <ul class="off-canvas-list">
                        <li><label>Users</label></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Hari Seldon</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </aside>
                <a class="exit-off-canvas"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h1 class="show-for-small-only">Phone</h1>
            <h1 class="show-for-medium-only">Medium</h1>
            <h1 class="show-for-large-only">Large</h1>
            Content Goes here
        </div>

        <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/foundation/foundation.offcanvas.js"></script>   
        <script>
            $(document).foundation();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I don't now why still doesn't work.
what is my code problems ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one you copied from [the documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/offcanvas.html#off-canvas-multilevel-menu) is missing the data attribute `data-offcanvas` for initialization within the example. Looks like I should submit a PR to fix this.

```
<div class="off-canvas-wrap show-for-small-only" data-offcanvas>
```

JSFiddle of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/5wzutp1g/

Comment: @Unique You're welcome, thanks for the upvote. It may interest you to know that I've submitted a PR to correct the docs: https://github.com/zurb/foundation/pull/5977